# In Nativescript, android, how to load buildconfig class?

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've configured the app.gradle file in order to create 2 variants (i've also tried with buildTypes) but i can´t load the BuildConfig class (in PackageName Namespace)

I always get undefined.

Could someone get in Typescript the final BuildConfig class ?

Comment: I've never done this, but do you have an example or could you show something in how this is done in a pure native android app without NativeScript? I could then possibly figure out what you're needing.

Comment: @BradMartin, in a native android app, when you use gradle, a final class is created, with a package "com.appname" in native project, you could just import it and access. In my Nativescript project, the buildconfig is generated, but i can't load it in the typescript code.

Comment: during the NS android build it should be created then since the build is the same process. Have you tried just `console.log(com.appname.class)` for the file that you expect to have? You can also look in `platforms/android` after a build of the NS app and it should mirror an android project so you should be able to locate the file after a build. Unless this is one of the things that NS needs to add support for directly, I've never used it myself so I'm not certain. Do let me know if you can locate the file in platforms/android.

Comment: @BradMartin, thanks for your soupport, but i've already solve it, indeed, you can access that class in com.appname.BuildConfig. I do not know why, but, when i delete the platform an re create it, it just work..